# POSTs that contain a semicolon are cut off after semicolon

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

If I have a POST parameter of

```
d={"data": "<span>hello</span>"}
```

which is a JSON string and it works fine and request.POST.get('d') contains the full string. But if I change it to

```
d = {"data": "<span>hel;lo</span>"}
print (request.POST.get('d')) #prints '{"data": "<span>hel'
```

For some reason anything after a semicolon is cut off. I can confirm this is not Javascript doing this because I used to use the exact same javascript code to post to a PHP API which was able to retrieve the data. Since moving to Python and webapp2 I've had this issue.

Comment: So what happens if you add \ before the ;?

Comment: Please show us how you're posting this parameter

Comment: I am posting using jQuery's $.ajax with data set to a JavaScript hashtable.

Comment: So *show* us how you're doing it.

Comment: `$.ajax({
  type: settings.method,
  async: true,
  url: url,
  data: JSON.stringify(settings.params),
  success: function() {
    //handler here
  }
});`

Comment: settings method is 'POST' and settings.params is a javascript hashtable

Comment: settings.params may be for example: `{'param1': 'test', 'param2': 'test', 'data': '<span>hel;lo</span>'. When I try to print() the whole JSON string it get's cut off before the semicolon

Answer (score 3):

Run your string through `encodeURIComponent()`. Then components that truncate would be encoded. Afterwards when retrieving the data you need to decode.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the `Content-Type` of the request. If content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then you need to urlencode the params. See first answer for a detailed explanation: [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)

Comment: This confuses me as to why I would need to do this. It worked fine when I was using a PHP API (with the exact same $.ajax() call). I'll try what you suggested though.